# Trying to Parse JSON date to POST to another System (Python)

Tags: python, json, insightly

I am trying to write a script to GET project data from Insightly and post to 10000ft. Essentially, I want to take any newly created project in one system and create that same instance in another system. Both have the concept of a 'Project'

I am extremely new at this but I only to GET certain Project parameters in Insightly to pass into the other system (PROJECT_NAME, LINKS:ORGANIZATION_ID, DATE_CREATED_UTC) to name a few.

I plan to add logic to only POST projects with a DATE_CREATED_UTC > yesterday, but I am clueless on how to setup the script to grab the JSON strings and create python variables (JSON datestring to datetime). Here is my current code. I am simply just printing out some of the variables I require to get comfortable with the code.

```
import urllib, urllib2, json, requests, pprint, dateutil
from dateutil import parser
import base64


#Set the 'Project' URL
insightly_url = 'https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/projects'
insightly_key = 
api_auth = base64.b64encode(insightly_key)


headers = {
                'GET': insightly_url,
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + api_auth

                }
req = urllib2.Request(insightly_url, None, headers)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

data = json.loads(response)
for project in data:
    project_date = project['DATE_CREATED_UTC']
    project_name = project['PROJECT_NAME']
    print project_name + " " + project_date
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edits:

I have updated the previous code with the following:

```
for project in data:
    project_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(project['DATE_CREATED_UTC'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
    if project_date > (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
        print project_date
    else:
        print 'No New Project'
```

This returns every project that was created after yesterday, but now I need to isolate these projects and post them to the other system

Comment: note: `data.today()` returns date in your local timezone (not UTC).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of returning a [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object from a parsed string. We will use the [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method to accomplish this. Here is a [list of the format codes](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) you can use to create a format string.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_string = '2014-03-04 22:30:55'
>>> format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>> datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 4, 22, 30, 55)
```

As you can see, the `datetime.strptime` method returns a `datetime` object.

Comment: Thanks @tsroten, I have updated the previous code with the following:                                                         for project in data:
    project_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(project['DATE_CREATED_UTC'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
    if project_date > (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
        print project_date
    else:
        print 'No New Project'                                           This gives me every project with a date created after yesterday. I now need to isolate these projects and post them to the new system